# Search for part of the stings on text files, print all the info including that string(Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to search (not as input) the gender and country of a person for example: Male and Canada. Python will read line for line then will print out all the info on the people who are male and from Canada.
In this case Python will print out Alex Baldwin and Gary Allen but not the rest of the people who doesnt meet the requirement(Male and Canada). It would print out all the persons info from name,last name, occupation, date of birth, gender and country of origin. Cant use regex and cant use command find. Anyone know how to do this? Any help is appreciated thanks.

This is the text files:

```
Alex              `*---stands for first name*`                 
Baldwin            *`---stands for last name`*  
Journalist         *`--- stands for occupation`*
03071989           *`--- stands for date of birth`*
M                  *`---- stands for gender`*
Canada             *`--- stands for country`*
Maria
Heizl
Doctor
27091977
F
Germany
Stephen
Chou
Actor
11041989
M
China
Gary
Allen
Dentist
16061981
M
Canada
```

Answer (score -1):

> You gonna need a Dictionnary with all your Data.

```
Dict_all_people={1:['Alex',    'Baldwin', 'Journalist', '03071989', 'M', 'Canada'],
                 2:['Maria',   'Heizl',   'Doctor',     '27091977', 'F', 'Germany'],
                 3:['Stephen', 'Chou',    'Actor',      '11041989', 'M', 'China'],
                 4:['Gary',    'Allen',   'Dentist',    '16061981', 'M', 'Canada']}


for i in Dict_all_people:
    if Dict_all_people[i][4] == 'M' and Dict_all_people[i][5] == 'Canada':
        print(Dict_all_people[i])
```

> Dict_all_people[i][0]= First Name
> Dict_all_people[i][1]= Last Name
> Dict_all_people[i][2]= Occupation
> Dict_all_people[i][3]= Birthday
> Dict_all_people[i][4]= Gender
> Dict_all_people[i][5]= Country
>
> == 'M' ** research only M gender
> == 'Canada' ** research only Canada country
>
> Hope that helped you, if you have question just ask!
> If this answer is good for you accept it to close the post

Comment: @SarahMiller Thx, i just dont get people here.. anyway i really hope that helped you, the harder part gonna be to do the dict with all your data